# React re-renders list items in same card instead of a list of cards

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I am doing a simple pokedex that should list all 1st gen pokemon, with the data being retrieved from https://pokeapi.co/

When I get to the screen, although I can see I have all the pokemon when I print, The list starts cycling and rerendering the same single card, instead of updating the list of cards and adding cards, instead  of replacing the already existent one.

I think my issue is with understanding the React render cycle. Can anybody please point me in the right direction?

Below is the page where I have a method that gets a single pokemon from the api, and this is the link to my github repo https://github.com/vradu007/poke-frontend.

Thank you!

```
const MainPage = (props) => {
    const [pokemons, setPokemons] = useState([]);
    
    const getPokemon = async (pokemonId) => {
        let pokemon = {};
        try {
            // const apiUrl = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokemon}`;
            // const res = await axios.get(apiUrl);
            // pokemons.push(res.data);
            pokemon = fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokemonId}`)
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((response) => setPokemons([...pokemons, response]))
                .then(() => {console.log(pokemons)});
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        for( let i = 0; i<151; i++){
            getPokemon(i);
        }
    },[]);

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Header title="Pokemon Page" />
            <PokemonList pokemons={pokemons} />
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your setState is async, your state update is dependent on your previous state so you need to give a callback to your `setPokemons` function.
This solution isn't good as you are updating your state way too many times than needed. The better way is already posted by another user, that is to only setState when all of your promises are resolved.

```
 pokemon = fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokemonId}`)
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((response) => setPokemons(pokemons => [...pokemons, response]))
                .then(() => {console.log(pokemons)});
```

Answer (score 2):

Edit - It can be done with React (the way as posted by vanshaj) but here is another performant way to do this :-

```
const MainPage = (props) => {
    const [pokemons, setPokemons] = useState([]);
    
    const getPokemon = async (pokemonId) => {
        try {
            const apiUrl = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokemonId}`;
            const res = await axios.get(apiUrl).then(res=>res.json());
            return res;
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
      async function gottaCatchEmAll(){
        const promises = [];
        for( let i = 0; i<151; i++){
            promises.push(getPokemon(i));
        }
       const pokemons = await Promise.all(promises);
       setPokemons(pokemons);
      }
    gottaCatchEmAll();
    },[]);

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Header title="Pokemon Page" />
            <PokemonList pokemons={pokemons} />
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};
```

In your implementation, you are trying to set the state in all the promises independently. What you need to ensure is that all these promises get resolved in an async manner as earlier but they are grouped together in a place such that when all of them get resolved ,a collective output can be returned which can be set as state in one pass. That grouping mechanism is `Promise.all`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info and code snippet. Just a quick issue, i get an "Unexpected reserved word 'await'" error on const pokemons = await gottaCatchEmAll(). Any idea why that is (should the useEffect anonymous function also be async?). Thank you

Comment: My bad. The await will go inside the async function. I have updated the code.

Comment: Like so? useEffect(async () => {
  async function gottaCatchEmAll() {
   const promises = [];
   for (let i = 0; i < 151; i++) {
    promises.push(getPokemon(i));
   }
   return Promise.all(promises);
  }
  const pokemons = await gottaCatchEmAll();
  setPokemons(pokemons);
 }, []);

Comment: `useEffect(async () => {
  async function gottaCatchEmAll() {
   const promises = [];
   for (let i = 0; i < 151; i++) {
    promises.push(getPokemon(i));
   }
   return Promise.all(promises);
  }
  const pokemons = await gottaCatchEmAll();
  setPokemons(pokemons);
 }, []);`